# Connecting a Raspberry-Pi to Android phone wirelessly

Tags: android, wifi, raspberry-pi, p2p, raspbian

I am trying to wirelessly connect my android phone to a Raspberry-Pi, so I can then make a controller app to interact with the RPi.

I have just bought a dongle, as I was thinking of using Wifi-Direct. However this doesn't look as simple as I originally thought.

There's not much information out there on how to do this, and I am completely new to RPis.
I have found the odd tutorial like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GPv8TfZqe4
But it seems overly complicated and I am not sure if they applicable to my dongle.

I am thinking there must be a more simple way to do this(e.g. through wpa_gui on Raspbian)

**Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- SSH to raspberry Pi with given credentials (if both devices are connected to the network... but that may not always be doable)
- Setup web API/app on RPi and use it via browser on Android (like https://github.com/NeonHorizon/berryio )
- Use Bluetooth UART: Adafruit has a full blown Bluetooth UART board, and Chinese make many slave (or master) UART serial boards. This way you could open a serial connection from the phone - and with luck you would get the terminal which by default is cloned to UART in RPi (or it would get your script running on Pi and handling incoming UART messages).

Comment: Yeah I might make the raspberrypi a server, then just interact with it through the internet. Seems a lot of people do that. Thanks :)